# undefined variable in CodeIgniter checked with print_r

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, view, model, foreach

I have this error in CI:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: controllers/First.php

Line Number: 33

A PHP Error was encountered



Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: views/welcome_view.php

Line Number: 1

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/welcome_view.php

Line Number: 1
```

There is my controller:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

   class First extends CI_Controller
   {
    
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('materials_model');
    }    
    
    
    public function index()
      {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('menu_view');
        $this->load->view('about_me_view');
        $this->load->view('navigation_view');
        $this->load->view('search_view');
        $this->load->view('main_text_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
       
      }
  
   
    public function mat()
    {
       $this->load->model('materials_model');
       $this->materials_model->get();
       $data['news'] = $this->materials_model->get();
    
       $this->load->view('welcome_view',$news);
    
       if(empty($data['news']))
       {
        echo'Array is Null';
       }
    
       else
       {
        echo'Array has info';
       }
    }
```

My model:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Materials_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('materials');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

     
}

?>
```

My view :

```
<?php foreach ($news as $one):?>
<?=$one['author']?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know, that array which I pass into the view IS NOT NULL (I check it for print_r and if, else construction), but I can pass it and view it. What mistake do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set variable:

```
$data['news'] = $this->materials_model->get();
```

Pass it to the view:

```
$this->load->view('welcome_view', isset($data) ? $data : NULL);
```

Access it in the view as a result array:

```
<?php 
    foreach($news as $item)
    {
        echo $item['id']." - ".$item['some_other_column_title']
    } 
?>
```

---

As an option, you can change your get() method in model to return object, not array.

```
public function get()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('materials');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Then in view you need handle $news as an object, like that:

```
<?php 
    foreach($news as $item)
    {
        echo $item->id." - ".$item->some_other_column_title
    } 
?>
```

Comment: No error , but on the screen is word 'Array', but I need information of this array. Can u help me?

Comment: @user1579200 $news is a result array, if you forgot. :) You can handle it as an array, or you can change get() function in your model to return result as an object, not as an array. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Comment: I've improved my answer, take a look.

Comment: With what function I can handle it as an object?

Comment: @user1579200 Khm, do you have any knowlege in OOP?

Comment: yes, but just a little :D . So, what i should change if I want handle it with result_array()?

Comment: @user1579200 If you're using result_array, you can access any column by $news_item['column_name']. What is not clear in CodeIgniter user guide? There are a lot of examples.

Comment: ok. I will hardly read the guide. Thank for wasted time for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->view('welcome_view',$news);
```

`$news` is never defined. Maybe you mean to use `$data`?, CI views expect an assoc array to be passed to them.

Comment: I try it. Error has remained.

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller you need to pass data not news like

```
$data['news'] = 'Something';
$this->load->view('welcome_view',$data);
```

and in your view you can use

```
foreach($news as $new)
{
   //Go Here
}
```